# UIWebView allow tapping but prevent scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a UIWebView (that has been sized to fully contain the html) and I want to put this web view into a UIScrollView along with a few other views.

If I set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the web view... it works perfectly except that I can't tap on a link in the web view. But, if I leave `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the web view... then, if the user swipes inside the web view rather than scrolling the UIScrollView it bounce the text around inside the web view (that's inside the scroll view).

Any help on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Piecing together a bunch of other answers... this works really well for me:

```
if ([_webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; // available starting in iOS 5
} else {
    for (id subview in _webView.subviews)
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled = NO;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes now that will happen , its like a scroll view on another scroll view and you can not scroll the parent scroll view when you scroll the child scroll view . I dont think what you want would be possible with this . Cause if the web page contents increases then the child webview is definitely going to scroll within around ....

Answer (score 0):

To turn off scrolling in `webView` you need to do this -

```
    for(id subview in self.scrollView.subviews)
    {
        if([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrolling = NO;
    }
```

What is happening here is we are looping through all the subviews inside your main `UIScrollView` & turning off scrolling for a view which is `UIWebView`. This is possible since `UIWebView` is inherited from `UIScrollView`.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** a correction. as @lxt points out - UIWebView does not inherit from UIScrollView. It contains a scroll view, but the web view itself is just a UIView subclass.

Comment: Couple of things: `UIWebView` *does not* inherit from `UIScrollView`. It contains a scroll view, but the web view itself is just a `UIView` subclass. Also, this answer needs a minor tweak to work on any OS other than iOS 5, since pre-5 the `scrollView` property of a web view wasn't publically available.

Answer (score 0):

I have one WebView "body" on my about view of my storyboard.

To prevent scrolling the "body"(WebView), this works great:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    ...
    body.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
  }
```

If the text is too large, its is behaves like HTML5/CSS3's "overflow: hidden".